# Regex: Replace Parentheses in JavaScript code with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to remove spaces, single quotes, and parens from a string displayed in as an `<li>`

This works great for the first two:

```
var foo = li.replace(/\s|\'+/g, "");
```

I assumed all I needed to do was add another few ORs to this, escaping the ( or ) symbols to search for them:

```
var foo = li.replace(/\s|\'+/g|\(|\), "");
```

Compiler no likey:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

It appears the the that the open and closing paren are getting evaluated anyway - even with the escape symbols. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the right syntax for [regex literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression). They're written as

```
/pattern/flags
```

And what you seem to want isn't a bunch of OR but a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Use

```
var foo = li.replace(/[\s'()]+/g, "");
```

Comment: Perfect. Really have to sit down and have a regex week-end to learn this stuff properly. Thanks for the links.